# WPF Client on Windows + WebService on a Linux server

Tags: wpf, linux, web-services

Currently I am developing a WPF application which will handle alot on the client (non business logic that is).

Some data (the business logic) will be coming from a SQL database. To expose this data to the client I was thinking to create a WebService. Normally I would use a WCF Service (or Web Api) to fix this. But in this scenario, there is only a linux server available using a MySQL database, on this server I am unable to host a WCF Service.

I was wondering how I could implement the following:

- Users opening the WPF client need to authenticate to the MySQL database.
- Users logged in should retrieve some of their personal data coming from the MySQL database.

Which kind of Webservice or technology is the best to go for?

Thanks

Comment: You can also create a WCF service using Mono, and deploy that to the Linux server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035873/best-way-to-make-linux-web-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a web service in any language, so it comes down to which ones you're comfortable with, or which offer the best tools. If you or your team are already heavily invested in the Microsoft stack, you could try something like Monodevelop: http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: Sorry for duplicate question! Im digging into monodevelop